# Canvas element creating strange effect in internet explorer 9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, internet-explorer-9

I am using a re-worked version of the hoverizr plugin that displays a canvas over the top of an image to do gray-scaling.

In every browser it is working fine, even IE9... Well except for one strange issue.

This shot shows what the brands are meant to look like, every brand has had the plugin called on it. (Ignore the blue rectangle, that was me having it selected in the F12 tools)
[image: Brands working]

And this shot shows what happens in IE9.
[image: Brands not working]

Now this only happens if the plugin is called, if it's not then they line up as in the first shot (albeit in the full colour version).
Ever more annoying is that I have no idea how to start debugging it, because as soon as you do hover over one of the brands it corrects itself!

Looking at the css that the horrible IE F12 tools gives you shows no difference before or after the hover. but something is going on!

So, any ideas on how I could start to debug this, or an answer as to what it going on?
Below is the script

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.hoverizr = function (settings) {
    var defaults = {
        /**
         * Is the image tag wrapped in a link?
         * If it is we will apply the effect on the
         * link becoming active as well
         */
        'link'     : false,
        /**
         * What effect do you wish to apply?
         * Possible values:
         * * grayscale
         * * invert
         * * blur
         * * noise
         */
        'effect'   : "grayscale",
        /**
         * How should we show the canvas element?
         * "top":
         * * Show canvased element by default
         * * Show original image upon hover
         * "bottom"
         * * Show original element by default
         * * Show canvased element upon hover
         */
        'overlay'  : "top",
        /**
         * What class should we give the container?
         * The container is created and wraps the
         * new canvas and image element
         */
        'container': "overlayed",
        /**
         * What class should we give the canvas?
         */
        'canvas'   : "canv",
        /**
         * What width should we give the canvas?
         * Also affects the original image
         */
        'width'    : "responsive",
        /**
         * What height should we give the canvas element
         * Also affects the original image
         */
        'height'   : "auto",
        /**
         * Should we allow the container to stretch to fill
         * all available space?
         */
        'stretch'  : "no",
        /**
         * How fast should the switch in be?
         */
        'speedIn'  : "slow",
        /**
         * How fast should the switch out be?
         */
        'speedOut' : "fast"
    };

    /**
     * Merge the defaults and the new settings together to give us
     * the user options
     */
    var options = $.extend(defaults, settings);

    this.each(function () {

        var containerOffset;
        var imageOffset;

        /**
         * We use this as a counter all over the place!
         */
        var i, j, k = 0;


        /**
         * Cache the jQuery selector for the image
         */
        var $image = $(this);
        var rawImage = this;

        /**
         * Create and cache the jQuery selector for the container
         */
        $image.wrap('<div class="'+options.container+'"></div>');
        var $container = $image.parent();



        /**
         * We wrap everything in .load() because we cannot
         * access the image data if it's not loaded yet!
         */

        $image.load(function () {


            /**
             * Set's the max-width of the image
             * Also, let's store a flag to say whether we
             * changed it or not
             */
            var maxWidthSet = false;
            if ($image.css('maxWidth') != "none") {
                maxWidthSet = true;
                $image.css('maxWidth', "none")
            }

            /**
             * Calculate the offset difference between the container
             * and the image, then we know how to properly position
             * the canvas element
             */

            containerOffset = $container.offset();
            imageOffset = $image.offset();
            var position = {
                top : imageOffset.top - containerOffset.top,
                left: imageOffset.left - containerOffset.left
            };

            /**
             * Create and cache the jQuery selector for the canvas
             */
            var $canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>', {class: options.canvas});
            var rawCanvas = $canvas.get(0);
            $container.append($canvas);



            /**
             * Let's store the image dimensions too, we will need to
             * give those to the canvas element
             */
            var dimensions = {
                height: $image.height(),
                width : $image.width()
            };
            $canvas.prop(dimensions);

            /**
             * We need the container to be relative so when we position
             * the canvas it is relative to the container
             */
            $container.css('position', 'relative');

            /**
             * Now we position the canvas so it should exactly cover the image
             */
            $canvas.css({'position': 'absolute', top: position.top, left: position.left, 'z-index': 10, display: 'block'});

            /**
             * Now let's set the Z-index so it sits in the right z-plane
             * relative to the canvas
             * Also, if the canvas is meant to be displayed only on hover
             * We might want to hide that too!
             */
            if (options.overlay == "top") {
                $image.css({'z-index': -1})
            } else {
                $image.css({'z-index': 1});
                $canvas.css({'display': 'none'});
            }

            /**
             * Get the Canvas in a 2d context and draw the image to it
             * in the upper left (0,0) hand corner
             */
            var rawCanvasContext2d = rawCanvas.getContext('2d');
            rawCanvasContext2d.drawImage(rawImage, 0, 0);

            /**
             * Apart from the noise an blur effects we will need to grab the image data
             * netscape has a quirk where you must ask for permission, so if we fail to
             * grab the image data we can try that (assuming netscape actually exists)
             * and then try again. If that fails then things are kaput and we will die.
             */
            if (options.effect != 'noise' && 'blur') {
                var canvasImage;
                try {
                    try {
                        canvasImage = rawCanvasContext2d.getImageData(0, 0, dimensions.width, dimensions.height)
                    } catch (e) {
                        if (typeof netscape !== 'undefined') {
                            netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
                        }
                        canvasImage = rawCanvasContext2d.getImageData(0, 0, dimensions.width, dimensions.height);

                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    throw new Error("unable to access image data: " + e)
                }

                var canvasImageData = canvasImage.data;
            }

            switch (options.effect) {

                case"invert":
                    for (i = 0; i < canvasImageData.length; i += 4) {
                        canvasImageData[i] = 255 - canvasImageData[i];
                        canvasImageData[i + 1] = 255 - canvasImageData[i + 1];
                        canvasImageData[i + 2] = 255 - canvasImageData[i + 2]
                    }
                    break;

                case"blur":
                    var newImage = new Image;
                    newImage.src = $image.prop('src');
                    rawCanvasContext2d.globalAlpha = 0.0625;
                    for (j = -3; j < 3; j += 1) {
                        for (k = -3; k < 3; k += 1) {
                            rawCanvasContext2d.drawImage(newImage, k, j)
                        }
                    }
                    rawCanvasContext2d.globalAlpha = 1;
                    break;

                default:
                    for (i = 0; i < canvasImageData.length; i += 4) {
                        var effectData = canvasImageData[i] * .3 +
                                         canvasImageData[i + 1] * .59 +
                                         canvasImageData[i + 2] * .11;
                        canvasImageData[i] = effectData;
                        canvasImageData[i + 1] = effectData;
                        canvasImageData[i + 2] = effectData
                    }
                    break
            }

            /**
             * Now that we have created the effect apart from blur and noise we need
             * to put the data back into the canvas2d context
             */
            if (options.effect != ("blur" || "noise")) {
                rawCanvasContext2d.putImageData(canvasImage, 0, 0);
            }

            /**
             * Now we can really play around with the positioning
             */
            if (options.width == "responsive") {
                $canvas.css({'max-width': '100%'});
                $image.css({'max-width': '100%'});
                $container.css({'width': '100%'})
            } else if (options.stretch == "no") {
                $container.css({'width': options.width, 'height': options.height, overflow: "hidden"})
            } else {
                $canvas.css({'width': options.width, 'height': options.height});
                $image.css({'width': m.width, 'height': m.height});
                $container.css({'width': m.width, 'height': m.height})
            }

            if (maxWidthSet) {
                $image.css('maxWidth', "100%")
            }

            /**
             * And now we can hook up the different events
             * We will add two new functions to the canvas element
             * so we only have to change them in one place,
             * also make the event handlers nicer
             */
            $canvas.in = function () {
                $canvas.stop(true, true).fadeIn(options.speedIn);
            };
            $canvas.out = function () {
                $canvas.stop(true, true).fadeOut(options.speedOut);
            };


            if (options.overlay == "top") {
                if (options.link) {
                    $(this).closest('a').on('focus', $canvas.out).on('blur', $canvas.in);
                }
                $container.hover($canvas.out, $canvas.in);
            } else {
                if (options.link) {
                    $(this).closest('a').on('focus', $canvas.in).on('blur', $canvas.out);
                }
                $container.hover($canvas.in, $canvas.out);
            }

        });

        /**
         * We re-assign the image src property because if the image
         * was loaded from cache before the plugin was initialized
         * the load event is never triggered, this triggers a reload
         */
        var src = $image.prop('src');
        $image.prop('src', '').prop('src', src);
    });


}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Most of the issues related to IE can be solved giving `float: left` or `positioning`. Try this once.

Comment: The canvas element get's given absolute position via this line: `$canvas.css({'position': 'absolute', top: position.top, left: position.left, 'z-index': 10, display: 'block'});`